# Maximize $\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, roots

$\cfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \cfrac{xe^x}{e^x-1} = \cfrac{e^{2x}-(x+1)e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} = 0$

From L'Hospital's we get $x=0$ as a root, but to find the other roots I have to solve $e^x-x-1=0$. How can I do this, or rather, how can I decide I can't?

Comment: There are no roots other than what you just found, you can prove this function is always positive, by proving it is decreasing towards $(0,0)$ and increasing from $(0,0)$ - I am taking about $e^x -x-1$

Comment: Look at the graphs of $y= e^x$ and $y= x+1$. You want to show they don't intersect when $x$ is strictly positive. Consider their slopes

Comment: There is no maximum. But there is a minimum at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {xe^{x}} {e^{x}-1} =\frac x {1-e^{-x}} \to \infty $ as $x \to \infty$. So there is no maximum.

Answer (score 4):

From expression you obtain for derivative follows that function is increasing.
Also
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{\cfrac{xe^x}{e^x-1}}=\infty$$
So ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The tangent to the curve $f(x)=\exp(x)$ at $x=0$ is the line $y=x+1$. 
 (slope of tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=c$ is $f'(c)$)

> $0$ is the only solution. However, in case you have equations like that involve both $\exp(x)$ and $x$, always pay a visit to the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).